# Pass a string to the stdin of a shell script via node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the simple-ssh to execute a shell script residing on my remote server . However shell-script waits for user input during execution  . I need to pass the password and directory name as string via my node.js/javascript .

```
./myscript.sh

Verifying .....

Retrieving information...
SSH password: 
Directory to store the output[/home]:
```

How do I pass the password and directory name as strings in javascript ?

Ideally I would like to create a variable

```
let ssh_pwd = 'password'
let dir_path = 'path/to/dir'
```

and pass these are string in the ssh.exec

So far I have tried to log into the remote server using simple-ssh and execute the following command .

```
cons { SSH } = require('simple-ssh');

var ssh = new SSH({
    host: hostname,
    user: username,
    pass: passwrod});

ssh.exec('cd /path/to/script/directory && ./myscript.sh --ask-pass' , {
            pty: true,
            out: function(stdout) {
                console.log(stdout);
            },
     })
    .start
```

Comment: `process.argv` is where your unparsed arguments live. If you'd like to have a nice wrapper over handling these params, I suggest you use something like [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander).

Comment: You need to pass password to `./myscript.sh` ?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to note:

First there's a typo (maybe copy/paste issue):

```
cons { SSH } = require('simple-ssh'); // <-- should be const
```

`SSH` is not a `named export` of the package `simple-ssh`, it's the `default export`, so you would have to import like:

```
const SSH = require('simple-ssh');
```

You can use `baseDir` option of the `config` to pass the directory where you want to execute. To pass input to `./myscript.sh` you can use `string interpolation`:

```
const SSH = require('simple-ssh');

const ssh_pwd = 'password'
const dir_path = '/path/to/script/directory'

const ssh = new SSH({
  host: hostname,
  user: username,
  pass: password, // <-- If ssh_pwd is password to login to ssh this is where you should be passing
  baseDir: dir_path
});

ssh.exec(`./myscript.sh --ask-pass ${ssh_pwd}` , {
  pty: true,
  out: function(stdout) {
    console.log(stdout);
  },
}).start()
```